# How to get Application Interface outside of a ViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, uialertcontroller, uiapplication

I have two files .h and .m with some util methods to be called from viewcontrollers. I have one with an alertview, which when the ok button is clicked, the app would terminate.

I will use the next code to exit, after user click the button:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] terminateWithSuccess];
```

I have a warning saying me that UIApplication shared doesn't have an interface.

My code:

```
    #pragma mark - SHOW ALERTVIEW FOR IOS 7 or less AND IOS 8
   +(void) showQuitAlert:(NSString*)alertTitle withMessage:(NSString *)alertMessage{

        NSString *alertOkButtonText = @"Accept";

      if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO( NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_8_0 ) ) {
              NSLog(@"iOS 8 dialog process");
             id rootViewController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController;

          if([rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]])
         {
            rootViewController = [((UINavigationController *)rootViewController).viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
         }

    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:alertTitle
                                                                             message:alertMessage
                                                                      preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    //We add buttons to the alert controller by creating UIAlertActions:
    UIAlertAction *actionOk = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:alertOkButtonText
                                                       style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                     handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                               {
                                   [alertController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] terminateWithSuccess];
                               }];


    UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction
                         actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                         style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                         handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                         {
                             [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                         }];
    UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction
                             actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                             style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                             handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                             {
                                 [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                             }];

    [alert addAction:ok];
    [alert addAction:cancel];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

    [alertController addAction:actionOk];
    [rootViewController presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_0) ) {
    NSLog(@"iOS 7 or less dialog process");

    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:alertTitle
                                                        message:alertMessage
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                              otherButtonTitles:alertOkButtonText, nil];
    [alertView show];
   }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: `terminateWithSuccess` is a function in a private API. You shouldn't be calling it.

Comment: See Apple's tech note: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1561/_index.html

Comment: I've just readed it, but what I mean is how I can terminate the app, or send the user to the home.

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to provide "Exit app" functionality in iOS, like in Android. Users should tap Home button to get to the Home screen. As simple as that.

Comment: I have a functionality in my app that I want only some users with a specified attribute in their profile could access it. So, I have 2 options, or give the functionality or go out.

Sorry if I don't explain me well.

Comment: Instead of going out you could just inform users that they are not allowed to do that. By means of alert view, for example.